# Geom_Bar Error With "labels = scales::comma"

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Newer R user here!
I wanted to customize the y-axis to show commas with custom breaks.

Here is what is looks like prior to trying to add commas:

```
ggplot(data = bike_data_v4, aes(x = member_casual, fill = rideable_type)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(title="Usage of Different Bike Types by Riders",
       x = "Rider Type", y = "Count") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,500000, 1000000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000))
```

[image]

When adding the scales::comma, I receive this error:

```
ggplot(data = bike_data_v4, aes(x = member_casual, fill = rideable_type)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(title="Usage of Different Bike Types by Riders",
       x = "Rider Type", y = "Count") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,500000, 1000000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000, labels = scales::comma))

Error in censor(breaks, self$trans$transform(limits), only.finite = FALSE) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I've read that this may need something like as.numeric(unlist(x)). The y-axis seems like just a count of the character variable "rideable_type" so I'm not sure how to manipulate things for this to work.

Comment: looks like you have a misplaced parenthesis. Close the vector of break values before you set the label: `scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,500000, 1000000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000), labels = scales::comma)`

Comment: ah, thank you so much. Those silly mistakes really take me down rabbit holes

Comment: fyi the clue here is that the error references a list object — if you create a vector with `c()` that has something other than a scalar as an element (here the function `scales::comma`) r automatically coerces the vector to list. So r thinks you are supplying a list to `breaks`!

Answer (score 0):

paqmo solved this for me!

"looks like you have a misplaced parenthesis. Close the vector of break values before you set the label: scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,500000, 1000000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000), labels = scales::comma)"

Thank you!